# I want to install package gi in the python, but it shows error and warning

Tags: python, pip, package

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement gi (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for gi
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.2.2 is available.
However, I use '''pip3 install --user --upgrade pip''' to check, it shows: Requirement already satisfied: pip in ./.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages (22.2.2)
I met the same problem when I installed other packages, I don' know why it shows I am using version 21.3.1.
Please, who can help me

Comment: What do you run to install the package? Are you sure this `gi` is a valid pypi package? Cehck https://pypi.org/search/?q=gi

Comment: What is your OS?

Comment: When gi displays red underline, a small box will appear automatically, which contains “install package gi”

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for [PyGobject](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) in that case, try `pip3 install PyGObject` or [follow the docs](https://pygobject.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#) to install it since the installation can vary depending on your platform.

Comment: Well, I have used `pip3 install PyGObject`,  and I can see it when I try `pip list`, but when I install PyGObject in the python, it shows the same problem : ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyGObject, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
WARNING: You are using pip version 21.3.1; however, version 22.2.2 is available.

Comment: What does it mean "when I install PyGObject in the python"? Also, pip and pip3 may point to different python installation. Be sure you are using the correct one. The warning is just a warning, won't affect the installation, it is only telling you that an upgrade of pip is available. While the error is now different from the one you posted. Please, describe exactly every command you have typed. Also, share the info about your system What is your OS? What version of Python are you running? Mind you can have python and python3 linked to different python installation. Please give us more info.

Comment: i mean although I can see PyGObject in pip list, there is still a red underline under gi, and when I move the mouse to the red underline, it will automatically come out: Install package gi/ Install package PyGObject...whichever I chose, the installation fails, the details show warning and error I mentioned above.

Comment: I can't help like this. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and learn [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).
In order to get help, you will need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Sorry, I'm a novice and I'm not good at English, but I solved it with this `sudo apt install libgirepository1.0-dev gcc libcairo2-dev pkg-config python3-dev gir1.2-gtk-3.0`. Thank you for your patience.